# Developed out of / off something

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between the following sentences if I were to use "off" instead of " out of" ? It seems like the usage of "off" an alternative. Are both acceptable?

> 1.But within psychology, the concept developed **out of** a growing emphasis
>   on research on the interaction of emotion and thought. (original sentence)

Source :http://eqi.org/salov2.htm

> 2.But within psychology, the concept developed **off** a growing emphasis on research on the interaction of emotion and thought.

Examples I found which apparently have similar structures, but they use "off" as follows:

> 3.The concept developed **off** the idea that whatever it was you were
>   looking to do or whatever problem you needed to solve, the answer or
>   solution could be found at the center.
>
> 4....a creation and concept developed brilliantly **off** a popular episode
>   of the old "Make Room for Daddy" show with Danny Thomas...

Comment: "off" is more colloquial here.

Comment: "sprang from," "evolved from," "originated in," "grew quite naturally from," "grew organically from," and  "emerged from" are some other options you may not have thought of. Don

Answer (score 2):

According to [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=developed+off%2C+developed+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0), the latter is rarely used.

Even more idiomatic however seems [**developed from**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=developed+off%2Cdeveloped+out+of%2C+developed+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20from%3B%2Cc0).

Which makes sense if you consider the dictionary definition of *from:*

> *from 10* Indicating a source of knowledge or the basis for one’s judgement:
>
> information obtained from papers, books, and presentations -[ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/from)